# Use Taylor Series to Show Speed is Not Linear

Tags: calculus

When $x$ is reasonably small (as $x \to 0$), a speed increase by $x$% will result in a time decrease by $x$%.

In a general case, the time would be multiplied by $\frac{100}{100+x}$. In the case of the small $x$ (decrease by $x$%), the time would be multiplied by $\frac{100-x}{100}$. If we look at the limits of these as $x\to 0$, they both result in an answer of $1$, which implies that they can be considered equivalent for all small $x$:
\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{100}{100+x}&=\\
\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{100-x}{100}&=1
\end{align*}
I am trying to come up with an explanation for this behavior using Taylor Series. How would this be done?

Comment: The fact they both have a limit of 1 is not really important. You can come up with infinitely many expressions that limit to 1. The question is why time decreasing by x percent is a good approximation to speed increasing by x percent.

Comment: Do not vandalise posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify things and avoiding writing 100s, let's define $x$ as the growth rate of speed:

$$x=\frac{\text{speed}_{\text{new}}-\text{speed}_{\text{old}}}{\text{speed}_{\text{old}}}.$$

You want to show for $x\approx 0$, speed having a growth rate of $x$ can be approximated by time having a growth rate of $-x$ (fixing distance):

$$\frac{1}{1+x}\approx 1-x.$$

This follows by noting that for $|x|<1$, we may write a geometric series

$$\frac{1}{1-(-x)}=1-x+x^2-x^3+...=1-x+O(x^2).$$

Comment: Could you explain the Big O notation to me? I am not sure how the final expansion follows to define the equivalence (sorry).

Comment: You can check out the formal definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#:~:text=Big%20O%20notation%20is%20a,a%20particular%20value%20or%20infinity.). Big O here is taken as $x\to 0$. Informally, this tells us the other terms are small enough to be ignored (on the order of $x^2$) giving a first order approximation of $1-x$.

Comment: If that confuses you, just feel free to write $1-x+x^2-x^3+...\approx 1-x$